Video live streaming with websockets
I am working on a project where I need to do a live stream using a webcam.
I work with web sockets and currently I use the AForge lib to get the images (Bitmaps) from my webcam.
Once I have the bitmap I put it in a byte array and then I directly send it to the client using a websocket. So I send bitmap per bitmap once at a time, but I am not sure that's the right way to do it. Can someone help me?
private void video_NewFrameSync(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
            {
                if (webSocket != null && webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    byte[] byteArray = BitmapToByteArray(bitmap);
                    var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(byteArray);

                    webSocket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                    


                }
            }
        }

I feel like the client won't even understand that it is a video that I want to send.

You need to use a video codec or it's going to take way too much bandwidth to get your images up to the client.
